# Looking to secure my public API end points from direct access to avoid putting my API url in browser or postman directly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, spring-security, backend

I am making a restful Spring Boot APIs, there are some **private API** end points as well as some are **public**. Private endpoints are secured by Spring security. and public api has **permit all** type access. I am just wondering, how can I make sure that my public API endpoints are **not called out** from direct hitting the api url (ex- https://backend.com/api/public). It should only called out from my frontend domains (ex- https://frontend.com/myapp), it should call my api using cros.

What approach need to be followed? I not quite know how is is done in IT industry, Please let me know how exacltly these works inside a organization.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Cross-Origin Requests to allow endpoint only when it comes through the particular origin

example

```
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080"); 
            }
        };
    }
```

now it will only allow when it comes through the origin localhost:8080

for more details https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I have added that in my code, but what I am actually looking for is, my spring apis are at localhost:8080 and react front end at localhost:3000 that's fine. But when you enter my public api end point (ex- localhost:8080/myapp/api/public) then you will get the data at that url even if you implemented cross-resource-origin. So my question is how to block that.